# Template overriding not working

Tags: magento-2.1, template, requirejs, overriding

I need to override the template:`module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`
I have created `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html':
                'Anime_Shipping/template/shipping.html'
        }
    }
};
```

I have created the copy of template file in: `app/code/Anime/Shipping/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`.
I have copied the whole code from original file to my own. I deployed the satic-content, cleared cache, compiled the code. The template does not seem to load. It is neither taking the original nor mine. What might be the problem?

Comment: are you using a custom theme?

Comment: You should copy the file Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html  inside your theme folder.

Comment: not using custom theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite absurd but I solved my problem by deleting the `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Anime_Shipping/template/shipping.html`.